# I cannot get new connection

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am having a problem with socket.io
There is no way I can see in the console.log when i try to connect to localhost:8080, the server is working but my socket which is properly bind to the server never says "new connection".

Can you help me please ?

```
import express from "express";
import socket from "socket.io";

const app = new express();
const server = app.listen(`${process.env.PORT_API}`, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${process.env.PORT_API}`);
});
const io = new socket(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log("new connection");
})
```

Comment: Could you show me your client side code - where you try to connect to the server?

Comment: Check in browser is you have event `101 protocol switching`. Socket.io like make queries by XHR, so if you want to control it, then use `ws`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', () => { 
  console.log("new connection");
 });
server.listen(`3000`, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port 3000`);
});
```

Reference: [Link here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io)